# Why does the code execute the second line when the first if statement is true?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle{
public static void main (String []args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the longest side: ");
    double longest = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd side: ");
    double second = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter 3rd side: ");
    double third = s.nextDouble();

    double longsq = longest*longest;
    double secondsq = second*second;
    double thirdsq = third*third;
    double secthirdsq = secondsq*thirdsq;

    if  (secthirdsq==longsq)
 {
    System.out.println("This triangle is an almost-Isosceles right triangle. ");

    }

    else if (secthirdsq!=longsq)

    {
    System.out.println("This triangle is not a right triangle. ");


}}
```

Here is the error I'm getting this>> .java:31: error: 'else' without 'if'
        else if (secthirdsq!=longsq);
        ^
1 error

I need it to print the first statement after the if not the one after else if

Edit: I changed it and now I am not able to get the first print line to print even when the first if-statement is true

Comment: Gotta love that class name! How fast can you spell "FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle".

Answer (score 2):

You have a semi colon at the end of your if statement. That semi colon ends the if statement, and the next block of code is seen as just a block and is executed no matter what.

You need to remove all your semi colons at the end of your if statements:

```
if  (secthirdsq==longsq)
{
...
}
else if (secthirdsq!=longsq)
{
...
```

Also your code looks to suffer from the inaccuracy of floating point calculations, try to compare like:

```
if (Math.abs(secthirdsq-longsq) < 0.001))
```

or just use whole numbers (like int). In addition, you probably just want an else instead of that else if, as you are comparing the opposite of what the preceding if is comparing.

Comment: And using an IDE's formatter will help make this sort of error obvious.

Comment: I fixed the error and now the code still produces the second line even when the value I plug in should produce the first line. Can you help?

Comment: @Kebur Can you edit your code to show the latest changes? What inputs are you using and what if do you expect to be hit?

Comment: I edited and I use 5, 4, and 3. After I use those inputs I expected the first if to be hit. And if I enter something like 2, 1, and 3 where 2^2+1^2(the 2nd and 3rd numbers) is not equal to 3^2(the longest number).

Comment: In this program you will prompt the user to enter the 3 sides of a triangle. You will determine if the triangle is an almost-Isosceles right (angled) triangle. You may assume that the inputs are integers. Isosceles right-angled triangles cannot have sides with integer values. However, there are infinitely many almost-isosceles right triangles. These are right-angled triangles with integral sides for which the lengths of the non-hypotenuse edges differ by one. Example: The triangle with sides 3, 4 and 5 is an almost-Isosceles right triangle.

Comment: @Kebur Your code looks to suffer from the inaccuracy of floating point calculations, try to compare like: `if (Math.abs(secthirdsq-longsq) < 0.001))', or just use whole numbers (like int). In addition, you probably just want an else instead of that else if, as you are comparing the opposite of what the preceding if is comparing.

Answer (score 1):

There are semicolons (`;`) after your if statements.  This doesn't work.

It's basically saying if condition is true, do nothing.  And then it executes the code in the `{}`s.  (Java allows for random `{}`s like this).

To correct your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle{
public static void main (String []args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the longest side: ");
        double longest = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd side: ");
        double second = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter 3rd side: ");
        double third = s.nextDouble();

        double longsq = longest*longest;
        double secondsq = second*second;
        double thirdsq = third*third;
        double secthirdsq = secondsq*thirdsq;

        if  (secthirdsq==longsq) {
            System.out.println("This triangle is an almost-Isosceles right triangle. ");

        }

        else if (secthirdsq!=longsq) {
            System.out.println("This triangle is not a right triangle. ");
        }

    }
}
```

As a side note, I recommend (though this is a personal preference) that you put the `{`s for if statements on the same line.  It will make errors like this more obvious - `if (condition); {` looks wrong at first glance.

Comment: I fixed the error and now the code still produces the second line even when the value I plug in should produce the first line. Can you help?

Comment: Can you give me some example input?  I have no idea what a `FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle` really should be.

Comment: In this program you will prompt the user to enter the 3 sides of a triangle. You will determine if the triangle is an almost-Isosceles right (angled) triangle. You may assume that the inputs are integers. Isosceles right-angled triangles cannot have sides with integer values. However, there are infinitely many almost-isosceles right triangles. These are right-angled triangles with integral sides for which the lengths of the non-hypotenuse edges differ by one. Example: The triangle with sides 3, 4 and 5 is an almost-Isosceles right triangle.

Comment: Ok, so here's another issue: secthirdsq should be `double secthirdsq = secondsq + thirdsq;`.  This fits with the Pythagorean theorem: `a²+b²=c²`.  What you currently have is `c²=(a²*b²)`, which is not accurate.

Comment: I realized it after I told it to print the incorrect secthirdsq, thank you.